# Making a fan site

Tags: flags

I'm trying to create an artist/fan base site. I have created content type(artist) and would want to add a "be a fan" tag to it. Where owner of content(artist) can see who fanned him and fan can see list of artists he's following.

I have tried drupal.org/projects/flag and changed bookmark to be a fan but its not working the way i want it to. Assistance needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing your flags types. Flags are defined for a specific entity. The bookmarks flag is defined for node. Once you have created a flag you cannot change its entity type to which it is attached. You want a users flag, which is displayed on user pages, and as you want it on a node page (content type artist) you will have to go the extra mile.

Look at this post which explains how to get the users flag in node.tpl.php

[Placing a flag link on a page](https://www.drupal.org/node/295383)